# df.to_html() method is displaying the actual html on the webpage and not the representation it should (Django website)

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, virtualenv, spyder

I'm currently making a django website for a Software Engineering class. I'm having a problem with displaying a pandas dataframe using the .to_html() method. The webpage template is rendering the actual html code on the UI instead of the representation of the html code. I don't understand why and have looked for similar problems on the internet. I think I can't find a similar problem because I don't know the right words to use in the search engine to get the answer I want. The webapp template (called graphs.html) is displaying the actual code itself. Here is a code fragment:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe"> <thead> <tr style="text-align: right;"> <th></th> <th>itemId</th> <th>title</th> <th>endPrice</th> <th>location</th> <th>endTime</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <th>0</th> <td>283584749546</td> <td>1979 80 TOPPS #18 WAYNE GRETZKY ROOKIE CARD PSA 6 EX-MINT</td> <td>500.0</td> <td>Canada</td> <td>2019-11-17T08:08:30.000Z</td> </tr> <tr> <th>1</th> <td>163940352354</td> <td>1979 Topps Hockey Unopened Wax Pack Gretzky PSA ?</td> <td>103.5</td> <td>Rice Lake,WI,USA</td> <td>2019-11-16T16:27:42.000Z</td> </tr> <tr> <th>2</th> <td>293329130191</td> <td>1979/80 Topps Wayne Gretzky Rookie #18 High End PSA 6 RC Priced to Sell</td> <td>345.0</td> <td>Liberty Lake,WA,USA</td> <td>2019-11-15T22:04:27.000Z</td> </tr> <tr>
```

As you can see, the UI is displaying html tags when it shouldn't. Below, the html is displaying without the tags showing, and would look like a formatted table on the User Interface. Instead, it should look something like this (except in a neat formatted table form):

itemId title endPrice location endTime     0 283584749546 1979 80 TOPPS #18 WAYNE GRETZKY ROOKIE CARD PSA 6 EX-MINT 500.0 Canada 2019-11-17T08:08:30.000Z   1 163940352354 1979 Topps Hockey Unopened Wax Pack Gretzky PSA ? 103.5 Rice Lake,WI,USA 2019-11-16T16:27:42.000Z   2 293329130191 1979/80 Topps Wayne Gretzky Rookie #18 High End PSA 6 RC Priced to Sell 345.0 Liberty Lake,WA,USA 2019-11-15T22:04:27.000Z

Here is my views.py for the graphs app in Django project:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection as finding
import xmltodict
from json import loads, dumps
import pandas as pd


def display_the_graphs(request):
    keywords = request.POST.get('search')
    api = finding(appid='JohnHein-homepage-PRD-392e94856-07aba7fe', config_file=None, siteid='EBAY-US')
    api_request = {'keywords':keywords, 'itemFilter':[{'name':'SoldItemsOnly', 'value':True},]}
    response = api.execute('findCompletedItems', api_request)
    content = response.content
    xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(content)
    content_dict = to_dict(xml_dict)
    count = content_dict['findCompletedItemsResponse']['searchResult']['@count']
    item_dict = content_dict['findCompletedItemsResponse']['searchResult']['item']
    print('count:', count)
    content_df = extract_values(item_dict)
    context = {'response':content_df.to_html()}
    return render(request, 'display_graphs/graphs.html', context)

def to_dict(input_ordered_dict):
    return loads(dumps(input_ordered_dict))

def extract_values(temp_dict):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['itemId','title','endPrice','location','endTime'])
    a = []
    b = []
    c = []
    d = []
    f = []
    #print('\ntype of data:\n', type(temp_dict))
    length = len(temp_dict)
    print('\nlength:\n', length)
    for index in range(length):
        for key, value in temp_dict[index].items():
            print('temp_dict[index][key]:', key)
            if key == 'itemId':
                a.append(value)
            if key == 'title':
                b.append(value)
            if key == 'sellingStatus':
                c.append(temp_dict[index]['sellingStatus']['currentPrice']['#text'])
            if key == 'location':
                d.append(value)
            if key == 'listingInfo':
                f.append(temp_dict[index]['listingInfo']['endTime'])
    df = pd.DataFrame({'itemId':pd.Series(a),'title':pd.Series(b),'endPrice':pd.Series(c),'location':pd.Series(d),'endTime':pd.Series(f)})  
    #print('\ndf:\n', df)
    #print('\narray a:\n', a)
    #print('\narray b:\n', b)
    #print('\narray c:\n', c)
    #print('\narray d:\n', d)
    #print('\narray f:\n', f)
    return df
```

Here is my graphs.html template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'display_graphs/style.css' %}">
    <title>Display graphs page</title>
    <style>
        ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #333;
        }

        li {
          float: left;
        }

        li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover:not(.active) {
          background-color: #111;
        }

        .active {
          background-color: #4CAF50;
        }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/about">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax5" align="center">
          <h1 style="background-color:white;align:center;color:red;padding:20px;width:50%;">Graph Page</h1>
              <p style="background-color:white;align:center;color:black;padding:50px;width:70%;">
                  Graphs are displayed below:<br>
                  {{ response }}
              </p><br>

      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've been stuck on this for hours and don't know what to do, so I'm coming back to Stackoverflow once again for help.

UPDATE: Daniel Roseman's comment about autoescaping the html worked (in the comment section below). I changed my html in graphs.html to:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ response }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

The df.to_html() is now working and showing the df table in the template.

Comment: [Automatic HTML escaping](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/language/#automatic-html-escaping)

Comment: Thank you Daniel Roseman. That worked. The dataframe now displays on the template. I wish I could upvote you or give you credit in some way. :)